# Create a new node by program and fill the specific field automatically

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

the goal of my program is to create a content of the specific content type

The specific content type (called A content type),have three fields:title,body,select option

when the user press a button, and the program will lead the user to the edit content page.

But the select option field will select the option i want and the AUTHENTICATED user can't

change this field.

How can i do?

the method i think is create a new node and fill the select field by programming. After

that, lead the user to the edit page of  the node  i just created.

but i still can't disable the select field

Does anybody have the suggestion? thx a lot !

i am not good at english. i hope you understand what i ask ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [field permission module](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) lets you define detailed permission on field level. If you have different types of users you may be want to define a new role for your users.

Comment: thx a lot , my problem is fixed by this module~